# Using VBA to hide rows in Excel if a Value returns 0

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create an automated proposal document, and when a certain value returns 0 in my spreadsheet, I want to hide a bunch of extraneous rows/graphics that are in those rows to reduce clutter and make a clean pdf to send out.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If .Range("F15").Value = "0" Then
        Rows("7:25").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ElseIf Range("f15").Value Then
      Rows("7:25").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If

End Sub
```

Where should I go from here? If f15 returns as a value greater than 0, I wish for the rows to be shown.

Comment: so first you comparing F15 to zero, so then you can use just `else` or `.Range("F15").value <> "0"` or `.Range("F15").value > 0`

Comment: If the cell has a formula you want the worksheet_calculate event.

Comment: @ScottCraner - `worksheet_change` can work as well as long as you test for the formula dependents in the event handler.

Comment: When I try to use <> or > it just gives me a compile error for expected:expression

Comment: @ScottHoltzman everytime I see you and Scott Craner post comments to each other, I can't help but think "Thanks for the pointer, Scott"  "You got it, Scott"  "Anytime, Scott"  :P

Comment: @JohnGustafson that's because you are looking at the string value of the cell, which will not allow a > or < comparator.  If the cell is numeric, you can use these, but otherwise you will have to pass the string value as numeric before it can be compared

Comment: @RGA how would I go about passing the string value as numeric? Sorry to be so ignorant, but this is the second day I've ever used VBA.

Comment: @JohnGustafson `CDbl` or `CLng` or `CInt` all work (depending on the data type that would work best)

Comment: You could change the whole `IF...END IF` statement to `Rows("7:25").EntireRow.Hidden = (Range("F15").Value = 0)`.   Range("F15").Value = 0 will return TRUE if it equals 0 and hide the rows, otherwise it will return FALSE and unhide the rows.  What do you want to happen if it's a minus number?

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook It won't ever be a minus number, its based on how much crude oil would be going into a possible second refinery.

Answer (score 0):

try this, holp it works

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If .Range("F15").Value = "0" Then
        Rows("7:25").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
        Rows("7:25").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If

End Sub
```